# DB2 Change Database Comment fails. Mostly

Tags: database, db2

I am using DB2 10.1 on CentOS7.

A very straightforward command is giving an error. I am trying to change the comments of all the databases from blank to something meaningful.

```
db2 change database mydb1 comment with "My First Database"
```

Simple enough to do. This command gave an error:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token ""My First Database"" was found following "WITH".  Expected tokens may include:  "<comment>".  SQLSTATE=42601`
```

Retrying a few times gave the same error. Then I tried using the DB2 shell:

```
db2
change database mydb1 comment with "My First Database"
```

What do you know? It worked.

So, I quickly gave the next command:

```
change database mydb2 comment with "My Second Database"
```

Same error.

Copied the command for mydb1. Result: Worked

Copy/pasted the command and changed the DB name to mydb2. Result: Failed

Any ideas?

Comment: If the `db2level` command does not show fixpack-6  (v10.1.0.6) then you should upgrade one Db2-instance to that level and retry.  The V10.1 is out of support since 30-Sept-2017 so if you are not at the final fixpack then expect errors.

Comment: Additionally, check if the behavior changes if you run `db2 terminate` after each successful change comment.  If that fails check the db2diag /diagnostics file for any additional details.

Comment: Ok, shall apply the fixpack. This is an old set of downloads of DB/2 and other packages for an installation which I was recreating on a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell is eating the double quotes. Try enclosing in single quotes or escaping them

```
db2 'change database bludb comment with "A Database"'
DB20000I  The CHANGE DATABASE COMMENT command completed successfully.

db2 change database bludb comment with \"A Database\"
DB20000I  The CHANGE DATABASE COMMENT command completed successfully.
```

Comment: The questions suggests that the symptom exists also in the interactive Db2 CLP (i.e. not only at the operating system shell).  So this answer may not be relevant.

Comment: As it turned out, there were two problems here. First was the double quoting. The second problem was that DB2 accepts DB comments of 30 characters only and gives this message if a longer one is typed.